# Finding value in array containing custom class

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to find the place of a value in a an array containing structures.
My array looks like this

```
struct User {
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
}

var allThePeople = [User(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"), User(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"), User(firstName: "John", lastName: "Travolta")];
```

Is there a way to get the places for all "Doe"'s in the array? (in this case 0 and 1)

Comment: You want the filtered array or the indexes for your condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter `allThePeople` with a condition to get all the people with the last name "Doe".

```
let allTheDoes = allThePeople.filter { $0.lastName == "Doe" }
```

You can enumerate the array and flat map it to an array of indices.

```
let allTheDoeIndexes = allThePeople.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element.lastName == "Doe" ? $0.offset : nil }
                     = allThePeople.enumerated().flatMap { $1.lastName == "Doe" ? $0 : nil }
```

Comment: The closure can be shortened slightly to `{ $1.lastName == "Doe" ? $0 : nil }` – perhaps a matter of taste.

Comment: Your `flatmap` is way more concise than my `for` loop answer (I upvoted you) - but it may be too terse for a novice - consider adding a bit of explanation?

Comment: Could I add more filters? Say I wanted to find the indices for all names with lastname Doe AND firstname John?

Comment: Yes you could do this `allThePeople.enumerated().flatMap { $1.firstName == "John" && $1.lastName == "Doe" ? $0 : nil }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the actual indices, use something like

```
struct User {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
}

var allThePeople = [User(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"), User(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"), User(firstName: "John", lastName: "Travolta")]

var indices = [Int]()
for i in 0 ..< allThePeople.count {
    if allThePeople[i].lastName == "Doe" {
        indices.append(i)
    }
}
indices // [0,1]
```

otherwise use `filter` as @Callam suggested.